# how to reload when i click ok swal button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "php/register.php",
  data: datas,
}).done(function(data) {
  swal(data),
    function() {
      location.reload();
    }
});
```

How to reload when I click ok on the `swal` button?
This is my code.

Answer (score 2):

The callback function should be passed to `swal`. You're currently defining it outside of the function call.

```
swal( data, function() {
   location.reload();
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/42843b2L/)

Comment: when i use this code we don't receive swal alert David!

Comment: @Weslyn: I don't understand what you mean by that. Care to elaborate?

Comment: $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/register.php",
                data: datas,
            }).done(function( data ) {
                swal( data, function()
                {
                  location.reload(); 
                });
            });                                                                                                             Now i changed but if i run my form in localhost.I don't recive popup alert

Comment: Is there an error? Is your `done` callback executing?

Comment: swal( data, function() {
                  location.reload(); 
                });

Comment: can you see screenshot? inside 

enter image description here

Comment: @Weslyn: I've updated my answer with a demo showing the code I've posted. What is the value of `data`? The error message you're showing indicates that you are getting a 404 for a script that sweetalert depends on. Does the path look alright? Does the script file exist?

Comment: path alright.. swal( data)
                {
                  location.reload(); 
                }    this code is working..but popup suddenly hidden

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "path alright". You have a 404 in the screenshot, so it's obviously not alright. The code you posted in your last comment has syntax errors, and I don't understand what you want to say by posting it..?